# A trigonometric limit $ \lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{\tan 3 x \sqrt{1-\cos 4 x}}{x^{2}+x^{3}} $

Tags: limits

I am stuck on evaluating the following limit:
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{\tan 3 x \sqrt{1-\cos 4 x}}{x^{2}+x^{3}}
$$
All I can think of is simplifying it in the form of $\sqrt{2}\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{\, \tan3x\, \sin2x}{x^3+x^2}$, but unsure where to go from there. I think one could get to an answer by applying the L'Hôpital's rule twice, but I was wondering whether there is a better approach that I'm missing.

Comment: That second expression should have a factor of $\sin(2x)$, not $\cos(2x)$.

Comment: @VarunVejalla $cos4x=cos^22x-sin^22x=2cos^22x-1$?

Comment: That's right, but if you plugged that in, it would make it $\sqrt{1-(2\cos^2(2x)-1)} = \sqrt{2-2\cos^2(2x)} = \sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-\cos^2(2x)}=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sin^2(2x)} = \sqrt{2}|\sin(2x)|$

Comment: @VarunVejalla Ops you're right, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{\tan 3 x \sqrt{1-\cos 4 x}}{x^{2}+x^{3}}=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{\tan 3 x \sqrt2 \sin(2x)}{x^{2}+x^{3}}=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{\frac{\tan 3 x}{3x} \sqrt2 \frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}\times6}{1+x}\\= 6\sqrt2
$$

I have used the following:

i)$|\sin(2x)|=\sin(2x)$ since $x\to0^+$

ii) $\lim_{t\to0} \frac{\sin t}{t}=\frac{\tan t}{t}=1$

Comment: Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is clear. Actually all the answers are pretty good, no idea who was down-voting them all... Just that shouldn't it be $\lim_{t\to0} \frac{\tan t}{t}$ in your last line? (not that it matters much, but for possible future references)

Answer (score 0):

Just do some basic *asymptotic analysis*:

- Near $0,\:$ a polynomial is asymptotically equivalent to its lowest degree term.
- $1-\cos u\sim_0 \dfrac{u^2}2$, $\;\tan u\sim_0u$.

Therefore
$$\frac{\tan 3 x \sqrt{1-\cos 4 x}}{x^{2}+x^{3}}\sim_0\frac{3x\sqrt{\frac{16x^2}2}}{x^2}=
\frac{6\sqrt 2x|x|}{|x|^2}=6\sqrt 2\frac x{|x|}=6\sqrt 2\operatorname{sgn}(x).$$
This yields also the limit when $x\to 0^-$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\cos(4x)=1-2\sin^2(2x)$, so we have

$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{\tan 3 x \sqrt{1-\cos 4 x}}{x^{2}+x^{3}}=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{6\sqrt 2\sin(2x)\sin(3x)}{\cos(3x)(2x)(3x)(1+x)}=6\sqrt{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by $\frac{\cos(3x)}{\cos(3x)}$ and note that $\lim_{x \to 0} \cos(x) = 1$ to get $$\sqrt{2} \lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{1}{x+1}\cdot\frac{\sin\left(3x\right)}{x} \cdot \frac{\sin(2x)}{x}$$

Because $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$, this simplifies to $$\sqrt{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1} \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 6\sqrt{2}$$